# How to rescale a NDSolve curve to fit in a box?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, graphics3d, output, scaling

I'm numerically solving some differential equations and the 3D curve I get has a very complicated shape and size that cannot be predicted from the initial conditions.

I need to rescale the whole curve to fit it entirely inside the cube defined below.  As a simple example, lets say the curve is this one (the real curve is much more complicated than that, and strongly depends on the initial conditions !) :

```
curve = ParametricPlot3D[
    {0.2 t (Sin[3 t] - 2), 0.2 t (Cos[5 t] + 1), t},
    {t, 0, 2Pi},
    Boxed -> True,
    PlotRange -> All,
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}
]
```

Now, I would like to rescale the whole curve so it fits entirely inside a centered cube of size 10 :

```
cube = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Cuboid[{-5, -5, -5}, {5, 5, 5}]}];

Show[{curve, cube},
    Axes -> True,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
    Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
    ImageSize -> {700, 700}
]
```

Take note that the curve is *starting at the origin* : `{0, 0, 0}`, and should still be starting at that same point after rescaling.

How can I do that rescaling ?

Just in case this is important :  the real curve would be shown with a `Manipulate` code, to change the initial conditions.  When I change these, the curve's shape and size change accordingly, but it still need to be rescaled to fit inside the same cube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  tab = Transpose[
   Table[{0.2 t (Sin[3 t] - 2), 0.2 t (Cos[5 t] + 1), t}, {t, 0, 2 Pi,
      0.001}]];
maxX = Max[{Abs[Min[tab[[1]]]], Abs[Max[tab[[1]]]]}];
maxY = Max[{Abs[Min[tab[[2]]]], Abs[Max[tab[[2]]]]}];
maxZ = Max[{Abs[Min[tab[[3]]]], Abs[Max[tab[[3]]]]}];
sc = 5*{1/maxX, 1/maxY, 1/maxZ};
Show[{Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], Cuboid[{-5, -5, -5}, {5, 5, 5}]}],

  ParametricPlot3D[{0.2 t (Sin[3 t] - 2), 0.2 t (Cos[5 t] + 1), t}*
    sc, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Boxed -> True, PlotRange -> All, Axes -> True, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}]
  }]
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: It's working.  I'll study this answer.  Thanks a lot !